# Parameterized build in Jenkins

Tags: unix, jenkins

We have created a Job for migration of Applications from one environment to another environment.  We checked the option "This Build is Parameterised" . In this we have created 3 Parameters. Source Environment, Application and Destination Environment.

Our Requirement is if we specify the first parameter (Source Environment), It should call a unix script and use the output of that script (list of applications deployed on that environment) as the second parameter (Application).

Is this possible to call a script if we select a parameter and the output should go in to the second parameter?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. All the parameters have to be specified before the build actually begins.
And all the choice parameters are static.

Do you expect the build to run for a while after you have given the first parameter and then wait for you to enter the second parameter based on the output? This is not possible. At the best you need to split your jobs where the first job provides output and triggers another parameterized build.